# Getting the ocrad.js demo to work?

Tags: javascript, ocr

I am trying to get this: https://github.com/antimatter15/ocrad.js demo to work for me. Some of the elements will show up and function correctly when I download the files and open up the .html on my home machine. Some of them will not--I can draw and upload pictures, but the text recognition script features do not run. Has anyone been successful in recreating an ocr javascript demo? I am using the code from the github link above.

Comment: What is the error you are getting on your console..?

Comment: I'm not getting any error--some of the elements just won't display. The text recognition works perfectly in this demo: http://antimatter15.com/ocrad.js/demo.html. Which I am trying to recreate. When I copy this code and use it in my browser, the text recognition does not work--no error even displays.

Comment: When you try run offline, it doens't work, because there are some external references, try to use firefox (verify the minimun version), with the  "web developer tools (adds-on)" in the console tab you will be able to see the problems. When you fix all the problems, run on Chrome browser.